# Installing Ipopt and CppAD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7

For a project in udacity, I am really stuck to install [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) and [CppAD](https://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/). Some people have asked about that but really no clear answer or actually no one found it. So my question is for someone how has the following spec:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2015+

How can he make these libraries run and work on his machine(**without docker**)? Any help?

Comment: This project should help compile Ipopt source codes on Windows using cmake tools. https://github.com/ampl/coin You can install CppAD in the same way. https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD Good luck !